# ant and aapt / changing package folder for R.java inside gen folder

Tags: java, android, ant, build-process, android-build

Within my project I have a folder named `versions`. 
This folder has sub-folders which represent flavors of the application (lets call them `x,y,z`).

Each flavor is released with different package name (com.example.[x,y,z]) . Therefore inside each folder I have different `AndrodManifest.xml` and `build.xml`.

Now.

Whole code is outside `versions` folder inside `src` dir. 
I did setup ant so that it finds resources from `versions` folder etc. There is one problem though.

For instance while building x flavour

java files within `src` have `import com.example.R`.
While building with aapt task the `R.java` file is generated into `~/versions/x/gen/com/example/x/R.java` so that `src` files cannot find it (as they import com.example.R)

How I can change aapt task so that `R.java` is generated within `~/versions/x/gen/com/example/R.java` ?

Comment: I've added a copy task that copies R.java to folder below, now the apk builds but there is noClassDefError on startup. Classes are not generated from *.java files.Hmm